# Using a USB camera with raspberry pi

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, kinect, webcam

I want to use raspistill with my USB Kinect camera. I managed to connect and use it with fswebcam, but when I type in raspistill -v -o test.jpg I get the following message:

```
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component.
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly.
```

Is there any way to make raspistill work with a webcam in /dev/video0?

Comment: Probably not the simplest solution, but you can most likely use OpenCV with python, for e.g.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because I want to stream video with RTSP using VLC. As far as I know that's only possible via raspistill.

Comment: not sure if this would work for you, but it's simple to do so it might be worth a shot: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17068/using-opencv-with-raspicam-and-python

Comment: ...or http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/?ALLSTEPS

Answer (score 0):

You see mmal complained about device not detected because it assumes you're using a raspi camera module connected to your Pi via Pi's `MIPI-CSI` interface, rather than a video device presented by your usb interface.

I guess mmal doesn't support a usb camera so basically you can't use raspistill with a usb camera, correct me if this is not true.